# Are there any ways to optimize this python iteration?

Tags: python, pandas

pivots is a list of numpy arrays given by:

```
pivots = []
for i in range(1, dimension):
    price_range = np.linspace(a, b, dimension//i).reshape(-1, 1)
    pdf = np.exp(kde.score_samples(price_range))
    peaks = find_peaks(pdf)[0]
    pivot_levels = price_range[peaks]
    pivots.append(pivot_levels)
```

My goal is it to have a pandas dataframe with two columns:

- 1st column: prices in range of 200, such as 30,000 - 30,200; 30,200 - 30,400. The column values should have the format of 30,000 - 30,200 or in other words "lower range value" - "upper range value"
- 2nd column: count the number of values across all arrays that fall in each range

What I tried so far takes a very long time:

```
# Create an empty DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Price Range', 'Count'])

# Define the price range step and format
step = 200
price_format = "{:,.0f} - {:,.0f}"

# Iterate over the pivots list
for i, pivot_levels in enumerate(pivots):
    # Iterate over the price ranges
    for lower_range in np.arange(a, b, step):
        upper_range = lower_range + step
        # Format the price range string
        price_range_str = price_format.format(lower_range, upper_range)
        # Count the number of values in the pivot_levels that fall within the current range
        count = np.sum((lower_range <= pivot_levels) & (pivot_levels < upper_range))
        # Append a new row to the DataFrame
        df = df.append({'Price Range': price_range_str, 'Count': count}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: So, are you looking for a histogram?    `numpy` can do that.

Comment: Yes, essentially. I was also interested in seeing this as a dataframe.

Comment: `numpy.histogram` produces an array that you can easily make into a dataframe.

Comment: I'm ultimately interested in making this code run faster tbh @TimRoberts

Comment: Do you mind sharing an example of using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it with numpy's `histogram`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

# Generate 10,000 values.

values = np.random.randint( 30000, 40000, 10000 )

# Divide them up into bins 200 units wide.

bins, edges = np.histogram( values, 50, (30000, 40000) )

lowend = edges[:-1]
highend = edges[1:]
df = pd.DataFrame( {'low': lowend, 'high': highend, 'counts': bins} )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        low     high  counts
0   30000.0  30200.0     239
1   30200.0  30400.0     192
2   30400.0  30600.0     208
3   30600.0  30800.0     193
4   30800.0  31000.0     200
5   31000.0  31200.0     204
6   31200.0  31400.0     189
7   31400.0  31600.0     202
8   31600.0  31800.0     204
9   31800.0  32000.0     180
10  32000.0  32200.0     194
11  32200.0  32400.0     183
12  32400.0  32600.0     209
13  32600.0  32800.0     202
14  32800.0  33000.0     212
15  33000.0  33200.0     196
16  33200.0  33400.0     189
17  33400.0  33600.0     199
18  33600.0  33800.0     202
19  33800.0  34000.0     194
20  34000.0  34200.0     210
21  34200.0  34400.0     203
22  34400.0  34600.0     184
23  34600.0  34800.0     184
24  34800.0  35000.0     192
25  35000.0  35200.0     199
26  35200.0  35400.0     184
27  35400.0  35600.0     211
28  35600.0  35800.0     195
29  35800.0  36000.0     208
30  36000.0  36200.0     196
31  36200.0  36400.0     218
32  36400.0  36600.0     190
33  36600.0  36800.0     205
34  36800.0  37000.0     193
35  37000.0  37200.0     184
36  37200.0  37400.0     195
37  37400.0  37600.0     237
38  37600.0  37800.0     205
39  37800.0  38000.0     197
40  38000.0  38200.0     222
41  38200.0  38400.0     220
42  38400.0  38600.0     212
43  38600.0  38800.0     195
44  38800.0  39000.0     193
45  39000.0  39200.0     197
46  39200.0  39400.0     189
47  39400.0  39600.0     197
48  39600.0  39800.0     205
49  39800.0  40000.0     189
```